# Performance measurements from Spectron

Tags: e2e-testing, spectron

Is there anyway to use Spectron to pull out performance metrics like fps? It would be very useful to know if our Electron app is staying performant as it's complexity grows.

I've been looking around online but don't see anything for WebdriverIO or Spectron. I also had a look at the Electron API but nothing seemed obvious. Even a way to dig into the dev tools might work, I wonder.

Answer (score 1):

Check out browser-perf: https://github.com/axemclion/browser-perf

You can use it with Spectron using the runner that comes along the browser-perf package. However it lacks documentation, so you might need to look into source codes to get some clue how to use it.